# (PHP/MYSQL) mysql_real_escape_string not working

Tags: php, mysql, flash, mysql-real-escape-string, insert-into

Recently, I've been having a problem with INSERT INTO not working properly when inserting certain strings. I discovered that the cause was the string contained apostrophes which were messing with my code. To solve this, I've been trying to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but it won't do anything. I read that it's supposed to insert \ before every "dangerous" special character, but when I echo'd the result of `mysql_real_escape_string()` it shows me the same string before and after, no \ s.
How do I fix this?
Here's my code...

```
<?php 

include "connect.php";  //connect.php connects to the database.

mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sdNamer']);
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sdTrunk']);
//$_POST['username'] and the rest is the data entered by the user. 
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sdName = $_POST['sdNamer'];
$sdTrunkest = $_POST['sdTrunk'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, user_bio, starterDeck, Trunk) VALUES ('$username', '$password', 'User', '$sdName', '$sdTrunkest')";
//INSERT INTO won't work, because $sdTrunkest has string that contains an apostrophe, and mysql_real_escape_string isn't doing anything about it.
mysql_query($sql); 
exit("result_message=Success");
?>
```

Comment: Assign mysql_escape_string return value to the variable ... And use mysqli ...

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[...]);` into where?

Comment: As your code is currently written, you're simply calling `mysql_real_escape_string()` multiple times ***before*** assigning the variable values. First assign the `$_POST` values to separate variables, and apply `mysql_real_escape_string()` like so (for *each* of them): `$foo = mysql_real_escape_string($foo);`. Better yet, stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` API and switch to PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` returns the modified string, but you're not doing anything with that string.  You're essentially *not using* `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  Use the returned value instead of the original unmodified value:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
// etc...
```

Also, as a side note, there are two more serious problems with your code:

1. Don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore.  Update your code.  (Read the introduction [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to get started.)
2. You're storing passwords in plain next.  ***Never store passwords in plain text.***

Comment: Thanks, I thought that when `mysql_real_escape_string` is used, it actually edits the target between brackets. And about #2... What should I store them as? Sorry, I'm absolutely new to PHP and Mysql.

Comment: @user3722253: You should hash the password.  For a lot of reading on the subject, take a look here: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm.  Essentially the goal is that the password should be put through a 1-way hash *immediately* upon receiving it at the server (so it also doesn't appear in other error conditions).  It's critical that this be 1-way so that the raw password can *never* be read, only its resulting hash string.  To compare passwords, you'd hash the supplied password and compare it with the stored hash.  You should never be able to *read* a user's password.